# How to pop on the top of stack once the tab is changed?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a tab bar with 4 tabs. Each of them have a stack navigator. I want to pop to Top once the tab is switched? I have an inkling it has to do with defaultNavigationOptions. Please suggest me something.

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

```
import {StackActions} from 'react-navigation'

defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state
        navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
        defaultHandler()
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();

function SettingsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Settings" 
          component={SettingsStackScreen} 
          listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
            tabPress: e => {
              // navigation.popToTop();
              navigation.navigate(route.name);
            },
          })}
      />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```